# Join two circles using a join function in Pyqt5

Tags: python, function, pyqt, pyqt5

I am trying to implement a function that will join two circles(with a line from center to center), by creating a list of lines for every pair of the circles that have to be joined. There was some error but when I passed two objects in circles list and corresponding center points to the lines list it worked. 
Could someone help to solve this issue to create a function that will join the circles when join button is clicked and two circles are selected by clicking
Below is the code, which when runs have two circles with a line and a functionlity to add more circles by clicking "Add" button. Or am I taking a wrong technique, Please suggest if anything is much simpler. Struggling for a long time... I am attaching a screenshot.[image]

```
import random
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMenu
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import QRect, QSize, QPoint, QLineF


class Window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()

        self.rect = QtCore.QRect()
        self.drag_position = QtCore.QPoint()
        self.circles = [QRect(100, 200, 100, 100), QRect(100, 300, 100, 100)]
        self.lines = []
        self.a = [0, 0, 500, 400]
        self.current_circle = None
        button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Add", self)
        button.clicked.connect(self.on_clicked)
        join = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Join", self)
        join.clicked.connect(self.joinAction)
        join.setGeometry(100, 0, 100, 30)
        Delete = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Delete", self)
        Delete.clicked.connect(self.DeleteItem)
        Delete.setGeometry(200, 0, 100, 30)
        self.resize(640, 480)


    def on_clicked(self):
        coor = QPoint(random.randrange(self.width() - 100), random.randrange(self.height()) - 100)
        self.circles.append(QRect(coor, QSize(100, 100)))
        self.update()

    def joinAction(self, event):
        pass


        contextMenu = QMenu(self)
        delAct = contextMenu.addAction("Delete Circle")
        action = contextMenu.exec_(self.mapToGlobal(event.pos()))
        if action == delAct:
            pass


    def DeleteItem(self):
        pass

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        super().paintEvent(event)

        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing)
        painter.setPen(QtGui.QPen(QtCore.Qt.black, 5, QtCore.Qt.SolidLine))
        for circle in self.circles:
            painter.drawEllipse(circle)
        # for line in self.lines:
        painter.drawLine(self.circles[0].center(), self.circles[1].center())

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        for circle in self.circles:
            line = QLineF(circle.center(), event.pos())

            if line.length() < circle.width() / 2:
                self.current_circle = circle
                self.drag_position = event.pos()
                break


    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if self.current_circle is not None:
            self.current_circle.translate(event.pos() - self.drag_position)
            self.drag_position = event.pos()
            self.update()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        self.current_circle = None


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Rect = Window()
    Rect.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Sorry to be rude, but you've been already warned. This is at least the fourth question in a week based on the same concepts (and code), for which you ask something, we answer, and then you ask something else practically using the same code of the previous answer with just some more bits and requests. This is a place where people answer to questions that show real efforts; if you've *really* tried (by studying the documentation and doing exercises like you've been already told to), then it means that you still have to do some more studying and practice to be able to achieve what you want to do.

Comment: I will try to be more specific I am new to StackOverflow. Sorry for any inconvenience.

Comment: You seem to have been "new" a few times (at least 4 if I counted correctly). Please, stop this behavior: it should be clear by now that you won't gain anything from it - and, I might add, it's quite offending. You've already been warned more than once, and your activity has already caught attention (which was easy, since you *always provide the same code*). Be *really* smarter: follow all the suggestions we've given you so far, study the documentation for both Python and Qt, do more practice and, most importantly, **learn from your mistakes** (which, if I may, is something you're *not* doing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to do it. I defined a `Circle` class with the attributes `line_to` and `line_from` to keep track of which circles are connected. A list is kept in the `Window` class, `last_two_clicked`, so when the join button is clicked, the two most recent circles that were pressed will be joined.

```
class Circle(QRect):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.line_to = self.line_from = None

    def join(self, other):
        self.line_to = other
        other.line_from = self
        if self.line_from and self.line_from.line_to == self:
            self.line_from.line_to = None
        self.line_from = other.line_to = None


class Window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()

        self.rect = QtCore.QRect()
        self.drag_position = QtCore.QPoint()
        self.circles = [Circle(100, 200, 100, 100), Circle(100, 300, 100, 100)]
        self.current_circle = None
        self.last_two_clicked = self.circles[:]

        button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Add", self)
        button.clicked.connect(self.on_clicked)
        join = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Join", self)
        join.clicked.connect(self.joinAction)
        join.setGeometry(100, 0, 100, 30)
        Delete = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Delete", self)
        Delete.clicked.connect(self.DeleteItem)
        Delete.setGeometry(200, 0, 100, 30)
        self.resize(640, 480)

    def on_clicked(self):
        coor = (random.randrange(self.width() - 100), random.randrange(self.height() - 100))
        c = Circle(*coor, 100, 100)
        self.circles.append(c)
        self.last_two_clicked.insert(0, c)
        self.last_two_clicked = self.last_two_clicked[:2]
        self.update()

    def joinAction(self, event):
        c1, c2 = self.last_two_clicked
        c1.join(c2)
        self.update()

    def DeleteItem(self):
        pass

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        super().paintEvent(event)

        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing)
        painter.setPen(QtGui.QPen(QtCore.Qt.black, 5, QtCore.Qt.SolidLine))
        for circle in self.circles:
            painter.drawEllipse(circle)
            if circle.line_to:
                painter.drawLine(circle.center(), circle.line_to.center())

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        for circle in self.circles:
            line = QLineF(circle.center(), event.pos())

            if line.length() < circle.width() / 2:
                self.current_circle = circle
                self.drag_position = event.pos()
                self.last_two_clicked.insert(0, circle)
                self.last_two_clicked = self.last_two_clicked[:2]
                break

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if self.current_circle is not None:
            self.current_circle.translate(event.pos() - self.drag_position)
            self.drag_position = event.pos()
            self.update()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        self.current_circle = None
```